# Objective-c: How to find UITableViewCell's containing UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've subclassed UITableView with some specific properties that I'd like to be able to access in a subclass of UITableViewCell. Is there something like cell.containingTableView that I'm just missing?

Comment: The cell's superview should be the table view. But a cell shouldn't need access to its table. Either pass the data to the cell when the cell is created or use a delegate pattern so the cell can ask its delegate (the table) for the needed data.

Comment: You can probably traverse the `superview` chain (not sure whether it's guaranteed to be direct superview), but this is a really strong code smell; if you have to ask you probably shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you don't want your views to know much of anything about their parents. The thing to do is subclass UITableViewCell, give it some properties to hold the information you want to pass to it and then let your UITableViewController do so in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Good point. I subclassed the cell and added a property pointing to my tableview. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You may think of using

```
self.superview
```

but it's **VERY** fragile, so please **DON'T**!.

You'd better pass a reference to the `UITableView` explicitly to the cell.

In your cell declare a property

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableView *parentTableView;
```

and assign it in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` data source method.

Finally if your purpose is just to call some methods on the parent controller, you can use a proper delegation pattern and define your own protocol

```
@protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)aMethodThatINeedToCall:(id)whatever;
@end
```

declare a delegate property

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CellDelegate> delegate;
```

and make your `UITableViewController` conform to that

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController <CellDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation

...

- (void)aMethodThatINeedToCall:(id)whatever {
    // do stuff
}

...

@end
```

Comment: As a very strong warning, `self.superview` is almost guaranteed to break eventually, and I'm hearing mutterings that iOS 7 may have reworked the view hierarchy for UITableView/UITVCell.

Comment: I already stated that it's pretty fragile, but I'll make it clearer